# Tensorflow object detection using non-consecutive class IDs

Tags: class, tensorflow, object, detection

I have trained a few models using the tensorflow object detection API. For now, my class IDs were from 1 to num_classes, zero being background. Is it possible for the graph to output IDs which are non-consecutive? For example, class 1 = 3, class 2 = 5 and class 3 = 8.

I thought about configuring the model so that I would have a num_classes equal to the highest ID and having some classes in between with no groundtruth, however at training time my precision stays at zero. Is this supposed to work?

Thank you,

-Smith

Comment: You should map the classes from 0 (background), num_class-1 (highest class id). Otherwise, the model will be trained for class ids with 0 examples. E.g.: if you have (2, 3). Map them to 1, 2 and then train the model.

Comment: I'M specifically looking for a way to the standard mapping.

Comment: It's a good suggestion, personally I have written code which internally does the mapping exactly for such scenarios. Not sure if object detection API provides interface/arguments to perform such kind of mapping automatically.